# How do i call C/C++ code from Android using JNA?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jna

I'm trying to integrate this specific library to my Android project, and the library is written in C/C++. I've miraculously gotten `ndk-build` to give me the needed `.so` file.

However, looking at it, there's a sample in the project, and they use a mysterious `.jar` with the API bindings of the `.c`/`c++` files.

How do i either

- create this special `.jar` file that has the API, based on the `.so`?

OR

- directly add a method to the main `c++` file and then call it from Java?

I've tried to re-wrap things using JNI, but it definitely doesn't seem to work. i keep getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

A lot of the documentation online uses jni as the tutorial. i'm happy with just a few links to tutorials on JNA.

Comment: Which language C or C++?  Very important.  The C++ language mangles the function names, whereas the C language doesn't.  Besides, there is no language called "C/C++".  Big difference when you are trying to call these functions from another language or platform.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews oh. let's say C++ then. honestly i would like to just have even a `return int` function actually get called from java

Comment: See the samples/ directory of the NDK distribution.  Build and try a few, studying how they work.

Comment: The distinction between JNA and JNI is also important.  JNA allows you to map Java functions onto native functions, and includes a native library you need to link into your android project.  In the case of JNI, you have to write some native code and compile it yourself.

Comment: @technomage oh perfect. when you say "... includes a native library you need to link into your android project". how do i generate this myself? i saw that the sample project has a jnidispatch.so and a corresponding `.jar` file but i have no idea how that got there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JNA provides a stub native library, `libjnidispatch.so` for a variety of platforms.  You can build this library yourself, or extract one of the pre-built binaries from the project's `lib/native/<platform>.jar` packages.

You include `libjnidispatch.so` in your Android project the way you would any other JNI library.  This is required; you cannot rely on JNA to dynamically unpack and use its native library automatically like on other platforms.  The JNA project [includes details for doing so](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/AndroidDevelopmentEnvironment.md) (as well as instructions for building `libjnidispatch.so` yourself).

You then use `jna.jar` as you would any other Java jar file, and write your own (Java) mappings to match the native library you're trying to access.  There's also a `jna-min.jar` which omits all the native platform libraries that are normally bundled in `jna.jar`.

Comment: i see. yeah, i never knew what `libjnidispatch.so` was for. i just knew it didn't work if i didn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Do go to project properties and build paths and remove JNA 4.0 and related classes.
This will work!