# jna : Could not find JNA native support

Tags: java, android, jna

I am using [this](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna) tutorial to use C in android, but I have an error at this line:

```
CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
```

This is the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find JNA native
>   support
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:754)
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.(Native.java:131)
>       ... 15 more

I put libctest.so in libs folder.
What's the problem?

Comment: `in android` no. this tutorial is unrelated to android.

Answer (score 0):

JNA is trying to load `libjnidispatch.o` and cannot find it.  If not found on the system, JNA attempts to unpack the appropriate library from `jna.jar`, which is apparently not in your classpath.

**EDIT**

In the case of android, you have to bundle `libjnidispatch.o` with your application explicitly.  Android will not allow JNA to unpack and load the native library on its own.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179833/how-do-i-call-c-c-code-from-android-using-jna/30215920#30215920).

Comment: but i have jna in my classpath [link](http://8pic.ir/images/6dwu2albtrzjo8qp85vu.jpg)