# The library 'jna-4.1.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device

Tags: java, android, httpclient, jna

I just installed httpclient in my eclipse Mars 2.0, I need this library for sending data to a server, however when I tried running my app I got this errors

`[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem] The library 'jna-4.1.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem] The following libraries were found:
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/linux-arm/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparc/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/freebsd-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/freebsd-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/openbsd-x86/libjnidispatch.so
[2016-03-19 17:46:43 - TrackingSystem]  - com/sun/jna/openbsd-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so`

I followed the instruction here: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/android-http-client.html but I'm having a problem with the library, I also tried downloading jna-4.2.0.jar but it still didn't work, please help! Android dev newbie here

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30215920/3080094) can help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i call C/C++ code from Android using JNA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179833/how-do-i-call-c-c-code-from-android-using-jna)